# phonegap using webservice with ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services, cordova

I'm using ajax to consuming my webservice. This is my code.js :

```
//button
$('#my_btn').live('click touchstart', function() {
   GetData();
});

function GetData() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.safetrace.com.br/safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws?op=consultarDados",
        //url: "http://www.safetrace.com.br/safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws/consultarDados",
        //data: {},
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
        alert("1)\njqXHR= " + jqXHR + "\njqXHR.status= " + jqXHR.status + "\njqXHR.readyState= " + jqXHR.readyState + "\nsettings= " + settings);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
           alert("2)\n" + msg);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("3)\njqXHR= " + jqXHR + "\ntextStatus= " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown= " + errorThrown + "\njqXHR.status= " + jqXHR.status + "\njqXHR.readyState= " + jqXHR.readyState);
        },
        complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("4)\njqXHR= " + jqXHR + "\ntextStatus= " + textStatus + "\njqXHR.status= " + jqXHR.status + "\njqXHR.readyState= " + jqXHR.readyState);
        }

    });

}
```

and my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />        

    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugin/cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="my_btn"></div>  

  </body>
</html>
```

when I run , I get just 'error!'

anyone know how to use ajax to consuming a webservice using phonegap ?

I know its possible, but I dont know how to do ! =/

phonegap FAQ:

> Q. I want to create an application for phonegap to access externally
>   deployed web services via AJAX. How can i resolve the issue with the
>   cross-domain security policy of XmlHttpRequest?
>
> A. The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap
>   applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the
>   file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply. (in Android,you
>   may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the
>   AndroidManifest.xml)

error print: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/CJZg3rn3FDKEWHDfrwzRaMbwwQCTg7vYm_5mSba6r006L6eTcbhvRKZyPWNbRsrMaRtDGv-IESw

Answer (score 0):

First, your URL seems to be wrong. Pasting it into a browser gets me:

> 404 The requested URL /safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws/consultarDados was not found on this server.

After you fix that you can try using a `GET` since you're not posting any data and removing `contentType`. Also, jQuery has `.getJSON()` which simplifies this even further.

#### Remove:

```js
data: {},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

#### Change:

```js
type: "GET",
```

#### Or Try:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( 'http://www.safetrace.com.br/safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws/consultarDados', 
    function() { alert( 'success' ); } )
    .error( function() { alert( 'error' ); } );
```

Comment: I still get 'error'! =/ 
I add this in error funcion: "error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)" and jqXHR=[object Object] , textStatus= error , errorThrown= Not Found !

Comment: @xazinn It appears you have your URL wrong. Paste it into the browser and it gets `not found` also.

Comment: my bad ! but I have this webservice: [link](http://www.safetrace.com.br/safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws?wsdl) and I need access the operation _consultarDados_ , and if I put url: http://www.safetrace.com.br/safefrigorifico/services/ServicoConsulta.jws?op=consultarDados still get error ! :(

Comment: @xazinn Your web service is return XML, not JSON.

Comment: really !? lol ! but even Json or XML I still dont know how get the information from this WS !